# Best practices for Hikari CP configuration for SQL Server for high performance and high traffic load

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have a server side application for processing data from SQL Server database. The frequency of the hitting the database is 100s of transactions per second in batch. I am using `Spring Boot 2.4.`1 which includes  `<hibernate.version>5.4.25.Final</hibernate.version>, <hikaricp.version>3.4.5</hikaricp.version>`
Also along with `Spring Data JPA`, I am using `SQLServerPreparedStatement` for bulk batch transactions calling `Stored Procedures` and also `INSERT`,`SELECT` queries, and uses the same `DB Connection Pool via EntityManager`.
My problem is, even if I increase the `Max Connection Pool` to like `500-600` it `cannot handle and connection timeout/connection cannot be acquired` kind of error occurs frequently. Once the max connection pool reaches, I think the connection is acquired but not released for pending transactions.
My configuration in application.properties is :

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name = SpringBootHikariCP
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 600
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle = 3
    spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime = 2000000
    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 30000
    spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout = 30000
    #spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
    #spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize = 250
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit = 2048
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useLocalSessionState = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.rewriteBatchedStatements = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheResultSetMetadata = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheServerConfiguration =  true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.elideSetAutoCommits = true
    spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.maintainTimeStats = false
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 20
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbschema
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=false
   #spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Please suggest an appropriate configuration for such traffic.
Main problems are : Connection time out and Connection pool being full.

There are multiple schedulers, normally 3, which extracts data from database and prepares data to save in batch. The schedulers run every second and extracts new unprocessed data(rows in that snap, can range from 1 or more) every second, processes and saves to database.

Please suggest efficient approaches for this kind of problem.

Comment: did you get any resolution ? Am facing similar issue.

Comment: It means that some of your SQL requests takes more then 30 seconds. Its too much.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the following doc:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

You must set your pool-size according to number of connections and number of Threads active. hence
pool size = Tn x (Cm - 1) + 1

Where Tn is the maximum number of threads, and Cm is the maximum number of simultaneous connections held by a single thread.

For example, imagine three threads (Tn=3), each of which requires four connections to perform some task (Cm=4). The pool size required to ensure that deadlock is never possible is:

pool size = 3 x (4 - 1) + 1 = 10